# Failing to pass a very long string as parameter in an ajax call to an asp.net controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my api controller, I need to pass two parameters: an integer + a string. This string is a json variable so it's a very long string, I can't pass as part of the URL.

I tried passing it as POST parameter (in the data attribute of the ajax call), but I get an error: only the first parameter is read, so the URL passed is not the right one.

How should I do this?

**EDIT**

JS code:

```
    function SavingFloor(FloorId, Json) {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('verifySession', verifySession());
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '@HttpContext.Current.Session["BaseAuth"]');
            },
            url: "/api/Floor/SaveFloor?FloorID=" + FloorId, //api: error in decoding json (the json can't be passed as parameter)
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                jsonstring: Json
            },
            dataType: 'text/html',
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveFloor(int floorID, string jsonstring)
    {
        Floor floor = db.FloorSet.Find(floorID);
        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonstring);
        floor.SavedJson = jsonstring;
        floorRepository.Update(floor);
        floorRepository.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Please post your JS and server side code.

Comment: String length is rather irrelevant, it has to be a problem in your code.

Comment: the string is very long (+8000). Please see the edits in the question.

Comment: GET is not designed for such long parameters, and even if it you set your server limits to accept longer queries (which is definitely not a best practice from a performance/stability/security perspective) some browsers may fail to send such long strings. I highly recommend you to give up GET and use POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding `[FromUri]` and `[FromBody]` attributes to the `SaveFloor` method. You can send floorID in regular `GET` and send the long `jsonstring` as the `POST` body. Currently, Web API can only read a single parameter from a `POST` body. You either need to encapsulate both variables in a single object, or try this:

```
public void SaveFloor([FromUri]int floorID, string jsonstring)
```

You don't need to specify `[FromBody]` to `jsonstring` as it's the default one in a `POST` request.
After this, don't forget to change your client-side code to send the `floorID` in the query string too.

Comment: I tried it and I still get the same error, only the floorID appears in the URL :(

Comment: Uhm.. Can you tell me, is this the same way to pass an array of integers? Or is there another method for that?

Comment: @SaharCh. you could encapsulate them and then send them to server. for example, create a single string variable which contains the comma seperated numbers and then send them in the POST body.